# Converting Undertow Java Library into an fs2 Streaming Library

Tags: java, scala, undertow, fs2

I am currently using `fs2-http` as a library for my JavaFX library written in Scala but as it stands, `fs2-http` is quite big of a library and has too many dependencies to be shipped as a desktop application whereby I need it to be as small as possible in terms of size and memory footprint while retaining the functionalities.

I resolved to using Undertow which is a Java Library but currently I am struggling with converting its components into Streams where my current functions that process the data are already streams.

So here's my question, how would I be able to convert this normal Java Library into a Streaming one?

Comment: What you are asking does not seem reasonable to me. Undertow is an http server written in Java. You can directly use it in a scala project, no problem. At the end you will be sending data into an http response so I am not even sure what you do before generating data (your "streaming") is relevant to the problem. Perhaps you can post some sample code of what you are currently doing with your http server.

Comment: Why not use http4s as the http server if you're using fs2?

Comment: @Daenyth I need the jar file as small as possible and also considering the memory foot print